# Why is momentjs converting the time zone the wrong way?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a form that schedules events. Part of the form is setting the event start time. The form has selection fields for Date, Time, and Timezone. I use this information with momentJS to build a dateTime called `eventTime`. The form should not submit if the selected DateTime is in the past. So I wrote some simple logic that says:

`timeDiff = moment(eventTime).diff(currentTime)`.

If `timeDiff` is less than zero the no submit.(More below) This is fine but I am having issues with timezones. So here is what I am trying to do:

If I currently reside in EST and it is 2:00pm then my form should not submit if select 1:45 EST on the given day. But if I change the "Time Zone" dropdown to "Central Time" Then it should submit. Assuming I am not thinking incorrectly

`1:45 CST = 2:45 EST`

Therefore since it is currently 2:00 CST the form should submit, but momentJS is going the other way and it is thinking the time is 1:45 EST. Based on the moment objects below (in UTC time) I would expect "Central Zone Moment Object" to be `Thu Jun 25 2020 10: 45: 00 GMT` instead of `Thu Jun 25 2020 08: 45: 00 GMT` what am I missing.

Thanks

```
let date = "2020-06-25";
let time = "13:45";
let timezoneEST = "America/New_York";
let timezoneCST = "America/Chicago";
let currentTime = moment().tz(moment.tz.guess());

let eventTimeEST = moment.tz(moment(date).set({ "hour": time.substring(0, 2), "minute": time.substring(3, 5) }), timezoneEST);
let eventTimeCST = moment.tz(moment(date).set({ "hour": time.substring(0, 2), "minute": time.substring(3, 5) }), timezoneCST);

timeDiff = moment([eventTimeEST or eventTimeCST]).diff(currentTime)
 if (timeDiff > 0) {
   // allow submit
 }


console.log(eventTimeEST)
// Eastern Zone Moment Object
// {
//   _isAMomentObject: true
//   _d: Thu Jun 25 2020 09: 45: 00 GMT - 0400(Eastern Daylight Time)
//   _i: Thu Jun 25 2020 00: 00: 00 GMT - 0400(Eastern Daylight Time)
//   _isAMomentObject: true
//   _isUTC: true
//   _isValid: true
//   _locale: Locale { _calendar: { … }, _longDateFormat: { … }, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, … }
//   _offset: -240
//   _pf: { empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, … }
//   _z: Zone { name: "America/New_York", abbrs: Array(236), untils: Array(236), offsets: Array(236), population: 21000000 }
// }

console.log(eventTimeCST)
// Central Zone Moment Object
// {
//   _isAMomentObject: true
//   _d: Thu Jun 25 2020 08: 45: 00 GMT - 0400(Eastern Daylight Time)
//   _i: Thu Jun 25 2020 00: 00: 00 GMT - 0400(Eastern Daylight Time)
//   _isAMomentObject: true
//   _isUTC: true
//   _isValid: true
//   _locale: Locale { _calendar: { … }, _longDateFormat: { … }, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, … }
//   _offset: -240
//   _pf: { empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, … }
//   _z: Zone { name: "America/New_York", abbrs: Array(236), untils: Array(236), offsets: Array(236), population: 21000000 }
// }

console.log(currentTime)
// Current Time(EST) Moment Object
// {
//   _d: Thu Jun 25 2020 09: 00:  GMT - 0400(Eastern Daylight Time)
//   _isAMomentObject: true
//   _isUTC: true
//   _isValid: true
//   _locale: Locale { _calendar: { … }, _longDateFormat: { … }, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, … }
//   _offset: -240
//   _pf: { empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, … }
//   _z: Zone { name: "America/New_York", abbrs: Array(236), untils: Array(236), offsets: Array(236), population: 21000000 }
//   __proto__: Object
// }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected

`let eventTimeCST = moment.tz(moment(date).set({ "hour": time.substring(0, 2), "minute": time.substring(3, 5) }), timezoneCST);`

creates a moment object in my timezone (EST) and the `.tz` adjusts that time zone. I needed to create a new moment object in the CST timeZone, compare it to my timezone.

That can be achieved like;

`let eventTimeCST = moment.tz({'year': 2020, 'month': 06, 'day': 26, 'hour': 9, 'minute': 30}, timezoneCST)`

So I just parsed out `date` and `time` and built the object.

FYI replacing

`{'year': 2020, 'month': 06, 'day': 26, 'hour': 9, 'minute': 30}`

with

`date + " " time`

also worked but threw a deprecation warning

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentTime = moment().tz(moment.tz.guess());

let eventTimeEST = moment.tz(moment(date).set({ "hour": time.substring(0, 2), "minute": time.substring(3, 5) }), timezoneEST);
let eventTimeCST = moment.tz(moment(date).set({ "hour": time.substring(0, 2), "minute": time.substring(3, 5) }), timezoneCST);
```

This code is basically setting a date in your current TZ and then translating it into another timezone (America/New York-America/Chicago).

The second statement is basically doing EDT to EDT.

The third statement is doing EDT to CDT.

That's why it goes back an hour. Because 1:45 PM EDT is 12:45 PM CDT.

But what you really want to do is to get the time at that timezone.

Eg. 1:45 PM CDT.

The way you do it is by basically setting the time on that timezone.

```js
let date = "2020-06-25";
let timezoneEDT = "America/New_York";
let timezoneCDT = "America/Chicago";

let notBefore = { hour : 14, minute : 0 };
let clock = { hour : 13, minute : 45 };

let a = moment(date).tz(timezoneEDT).set(notBefore); //14:00 EDT
let b = moment(date).tz(timezoneCDT).set(clock); //13:45 CDT -> 14:45 EDT
let c = moment(date).tz(timezoneEDT).set(clock); //13:45 EDT

console.log(test(a, b)); //14:00 EDT against 14:45 EDT prints valid
console.log(test(a, c)); //13:45 EDT against 14:00 EDT prints invalid

function test(a,b){
  return a.diff(b) > 0 ? 'Invalid date' : 'Valid date';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js"></script>
```

Comment: but running the snippet rseolve both invalid. In fact `b` is trying set to the previous day for some reason. The right time but the previous day

Comment: Are you running this snippet somewhere else or on SO? It works fine here. All 3 dates show up correctly too. The date it's using is fixed to 06-25-2020, so that's yesterday.

Comment: Ran it on SO and JS Fiddle same result. Both returned invalid Date, but i did figure out the answer.